# Error Uncaught TypeError: numbers.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with reactjs and cannot seem to prevent this error when trying to map an array

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


function Tasks(props) {
  const numbers = props.items;
  
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <li>{numbers}</li>
  );
  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
}

export default Tasks;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Changing the numbers constant to a defined value (e.g. `["test1","test2"]`) fixes it but that's not I want.

Comment: could you provide the component that is using `Tasks`?

Comment: What is `props.items`? Chances are, you are not passing in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try console logging numbers, I want to guess it should be something like this you should do 'numbers.numbers.map' - reason is that I'm guessing props.item is an array called numbers, so you're not deep matching I'd say. But first let's see the console's log.